# Email notifications for new questions matching specific tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, feed, email

Is there a way to configure your Stack Overflow account so that you receive notification emails when posts are made to specific tags?

Or do you simply have to log on to see new posts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- Click on a tag
- Check your browser notification spot that shows up the RSS icon
- Click and [subscribe to the RSS for that tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/waffles).

It's not email, but it's just as in your face as you want it to be.

Comment: The RSS feed is very hard to miss, yet many people spend time looking for a way to get such alerts by email.  If anything, this should be a good indicator that (at least some) people *really* do want *email* notifications.  Something active, not a passive RSS feed.

Comment: Agreed with Zee! It would be as easy as making the feeds PubSubHubbub though... so I can susbcribe to them via my IM client for example and get pings whenever they update!

Comment: The RSS are not alive anymore. I found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93054/subscribe-to-tags-i-am-interested-in which is also interesting. Ah, and the other answers also refer to this! I should have double checked! :D

Comment: @random the link is broken

Answer (score 82):

[Tag sets on Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/) now support **emailing you as new questions arrive in your tag set.**

To set it up:

- visit the [tag sets page](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets) at stackexchange.com
- browse someone else's tag set *or* establish your own tag set
- look in the right hand sidebar for the envelope to enable email options

[image]

Remember that Tag Sets work across *all* Stack Exchange websites -- so you are not limited to a single site.

Comment: This appears to no longer be the case?

Comment: @mike.bronner — I was looking at this today (2020-04-24) to help a colleague. It looks as if it should work.  I've not actually created a new subscription today, but the 'Email Updates' box with reddish envelope icon is present when I choose one of my existing subscriptions.

Comment: It appears that this is impossible for Meta Stack Exchange (the site we're on right now)?

Comment: @user1271772 Click checkbox "show meta sites" to the right of "all sites".

Answer (score 10):

In addition [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72451/163250), you can also subscribe for email updates for your favorite tags without having to leave your particular exchange to visit [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) (not sure when this was implemented).

Simply hover your cursor over the tag that you want to subscribe to, and a little popup will appear:

[image: Screenshot]

Click on **subscribe**, and the popup will then say that you've been sent a confirmation email.

Visit your email inbox, and click on the confirmation link in the confirmation email, and that's it! I'm not sure if this method will allow you to subscribe to email alerts every 15 minutes or 3 hours though (like in Jeff's method), I think it might be set to a daily frequency.

Comment: The tag popup now only allows to subscribe to the tag's RSS feed.

Answer (score 3):

@random is exactly right, but if you still want email notifications on top of RSS, you can easily set up a [**FeedBurner**](http://feedburner.com) feed - just grab the feed address, sign in with your Google account to [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.com), paste the address in, and under the **Publicize** tab, enable Email Subscriptions. Of course, you can set up email delivery times, branding, etc. I use this a lot for all the feeds I want to keep track of - I just always forget to open Google Reader...

Comment: However FeedBurner currently has a fixed interval of one day. Getting email notifications more frequently is currently not supported. :(

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry if this is inappropriate to write a response as an answer, a comment is too short, and someplace else it was indicated that adding answers is a way to vote up an issue.)

@Maxim Z. --

I just tried it -- it's a very weak solution.  First, it takes about 327 steps to get email notifications this way:

- go to the tag questions,
- get the feed url,
- create the feedburner feed,
- fill in details,
- enable email subscriptions,
- find the link for subscribing,
- subscribe,
- wait for verification email,
- verify,
- finally breathe and think "that's something that a machine should have done; I should have just clicked a little box and typed `foo`.

Sure -- some people are always glued to their readers; but some are just as glued to their emails, spending time to make sure that all information flows through a single channel makes it very convenient to keep track of everything.

And note that I *did* read through [some](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/02/podcast-83/) of the explanations.  "Efail" seems to be a complaint about emails from people -- the kind of messages that you need to reply to and feel bad if you don't.  Notification emails are *not* in this category.  There was also a point made on how wonderfully flexible readers like google's are at filtering feeds etc -- I've used it (g-reader) a few times, and it has far, far less ways to filter feeds.  I mean, *come on, are you serious??* -- this should be a place for hackers, are you really comparing a feed reader filtering capabilities to the stuff that you can do with email??  Give me a few short lines of procmail, and I'll make my computers dance around your readers.  Even that feedburner thing is basically just a lame metaphor for email forwarding, only adapted to feeds -- and it's *that* much more difficult to use it than to set up a forward using practically anything.

So yes, feeds can be awfully convenient -- but email is far more flexible in terms of what you can do with it.  Comparing the two is like hearing an iPad user try to convince a hacker that there's no need for desktops and laptops anymore *just* because the iPad does everything *iPad users* will ever want to do.

---

To tell the truth, I originally though that the real reason SO etc avoid emails is to lower network and maintenance costs.  But neither of these make sense: there's almost zero maintenance for *outbound* emails, and surely the constant requests for feed updates is much greater than sending out emails when an event like a new question happens.  I could probably even measure the number of notifications I would get times the size of such a note, vs the load of my scripts running every few minutes and mostly get a bunch of data only to conclude "nah, nothing new".

Answer (score 1):

The current address for this kind of notifications is
https://stackexchange.com/filters/