# Monitor Stack Overflow tags?

Tags: support, tags, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Email notifications for new questions matching specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags)

[I know how to combine several tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/). But I would prefer to get emailed every time a new question with one of my tags is posted.
Is there a way to monitor a collection of tags on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

You could always subscribe to [the rss feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags).