# Subscribe to tags I am interested in?

Tags: support, tag-watching, feed, email-notification

How do I subscribe to the tags that I am interested in?

I like to get notified via email or so, when someone asks new questions or if someone responds to my questions.

Answer (score 7):

Mouse over the tag and you will see links to subscribe via email or RSS:
[image: "tag mouserover"]

To subscribe to answers in one of your questions, there's a form at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page where you can request that:[image: "email notification"]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Anna correctly noted, you can also subscribe to a group of tags as a "Tag Filter" at https://stackexchange.com/filters

For an overview, see:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/

Comment: Is there any way to subscribe not just to tags but to particular search terms (the message body should also be searched, automatically) which are not particularly tags? Tags are quite common, while some specific terms may not be tags. So how to just subscribe to words, not to tags?

Comment: Can we subscribe/filter to "tag1 AND tag2"? The UI does not seem to allow so.

Answer (score 4):

@RayLuo From what I saw on https://stackexchange.com/filters, you can add several filters to subscribe to multiple tags. See the screenshot: [image]