# Instant notifications when a question is posted

Tags: support, notifications

How can I receive instant notifications when a question is posted on a Tag that I am subscribed to. Presently you can [subscribe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93054/subscribe-to-tags-i-am-interested-in) to Tabs and only have the following notification options.

- Every 15 minutes
- Every 3 hours
- Every Day

I understand that for popular tags there might be too many notifications. But I want to do this for less popular tags.

Comment: You can use the RSS feed with whatever application you prefer to have whatever settings you want for notification of new questions.

Comment: Install an userscript? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250762/how-can-i-make-stack-overflow-make-a-sound-when-a-new-question-appears/250769#250769