# Is there a subscription feature to notify me of new questions in with two or more tags (or new search results)?

Tags: feature-request, support

I would like to get an email alert when new questions appear which have at least two tags that I chose. If a subscribe to a single tag only, I get way to much questions that are not interesting to me.

Another way to achieve this would be the notification upon new search results.

Is that possible?

Comment: So, in a nutshell, you are looking to get notifications on custom searches? (or along those lines)

Comment: yes, that sums it up

Comment: possible duplicate of [Email notifications for new questions matching specific tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags), [RSS feed of your favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags), [Is there a way to do RSS feeds on a set of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/is-there-a-way-to-do-rss-feeds-on-a-set-of-tags)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Cody Gray. [http://stackexchange.com/filters/](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) helps with email alerts, however, combining tags is not supported. RSS would be a possibility to combined tags, but is not convenient as email for me.