# confused about stackX

Tags: support, stack-exchange, meta-faq

I found this site when searching for answers to programming questions.  I created an account to ask some questions. I got good response to my questions.

My questions:

1. I came across some doc about formatting a question.  I cannot find it again.
2. How do a find the list of "forums?"  I'd like to see the python forum.
3. There seems to be other similar sites. Like stachexchange.  Why did it create a second id or maybe third for meta.
4. What is the best way of staying logged in.  I have a bookmark to my status page.  Seems that it logs me in.  When I more to somewhere else I get logged out.  Like this page.
5. What tutorials do you recommend
6. I'd like to follow a forum.  How do I do that.

I've looked around the help & faqs, but I seem to not be finding this info.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not clear on your question regarding point #3. Please consider an [edit] to your post to clarify. Good luck! :)

Comment: Formatting: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: About your accounts, I use Google OAuth, so when I create an account on a new SE site, I use the same login details so my accounts are automatically linked together. You might describe what type of login you're using:  Stack Exchange, Google OAuth, something else?

Answer (score 8):

First, Stack Exchange sites are not forums. Instead, they are questions and answers sites. The key distinction is that the Q&A format doesn't leave room for extended discussions like a forum would. SE's Q&A format has very specific rules where answers absolutely must answer the question, and questions must meet specific requirements outlined in each site's [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/faq). This is an important difference to note to avoid having trouble with the communities you post questions or answers on.

Second, there is no site specifically for Python, as any programming problems are handled by Stack Overflow. See the [List of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for a broader picture of what sites are currently available.

Lastly, you can subscribe to certain tags on a site and receive email notifications. I'm not entirely sure how this works, as I prefer to keep Stack Exchange separate from my email. However, [instructions are found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72451/155826).

As far as tutorials go, see the [About Page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) as well as each site's FAQ. Of course, if you ever have questions about how Stack Exchange works, please be sure to search first, as your question has likely already been asked and answered by others. Good luck, and welcome to Stack Exchange! :)

Comment: His third point: He's trying to figure out why he needs an individual account for each SE site, why he can't just use one account for every site.

Comment: He...basically can, right? Your rep and badges don't transfer, but there doesn't seem to me to be a huge difference between linked profiles and a single "network profile".

Comment: @cpast - If he creates new accounts each time using a different email address, they won't be linked, and he won't get the 100 rep association bonuses or a single network profile. It's advantageous to have accounts linked. Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253 Even if you do link the accounts though, they are different accounts, and you need to go create a new account (even if you immediately link it with your existing account) when you login to a new site for the first time.  This process apparently confused him.