# Subscribe to site

Tags: support, stack-exchange, email-notification

I'm interested in a site which still is in beta and has a very low traffic. I'd want to get notified as soon as a new question is posted on that site, since they are few. I know we can [subscirbe to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions) and [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72451/321196), but I'd want to get an instant email when a new question is published on that specific SE site, with any tag. Is that possible?

Comment: This feature isn't implemented as far as I know and the biggest problem with implementing is that SE sites never remain the same size.

Comment: Just use RSS...

Answer (score 4):

Right now there is no way to get an email for each and every new question on a site. There are two other options you have though:

1. Use the rss feed. At the bottom of every site's homepage is a "recent questions feed" link which you can use in your favorite rss reader. Depending on the reader you use, you could get a notification similar to email.
2. Subscribe to the [newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters). However, this only gives a periodic email about the most popular posts from a given timeframe. This is not ideal for instant notification.

You could also go crazy with the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), or the [realtime tab](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime), but these require much more work to use.